# How to create Outlook date file (.pst) inside the mailbox?

Tags: outlook, pst

Trying to create a script that would create Outlook data file (pst) for the current out user. any pointer on where to look for ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Namespace.AddStore or Namespace.AddStoreEx in the OUtlook Object Model to create a new PST store in teh current profile.